How do I choose between parquet and delta format when overwriting data into a parquet file?
I'm new to Azure data bricks.
Using Azure data bricks notebook I'm reading data from a parquet file into a df (Bronze layer). Then doing some transformations like date format.
Now I want to save this data back into the parquet file (Bronze Layer). For this I have 2 options:
df.write.format("delta").save("/path/to/output")

df.write.format("parquet").save("/path/to/output")


How do I choose which one to use?

Do I need to specify mode as overwrite or is that the default mode?

If I want to store this data into Silver layer, then which option is suitable? (Parquet or delta)?



To understand the basic difference, you need to learn more about Delta. https://docs.databricks.com/en/introduction/delta-comparison.html
Parquet is a physical file format, whereas Delta format is not. Even if you save as Delta, the actual files will be in Parquet format along with Transaction log files.
Delta offers a lot more benefits, so it's better to store Silver and Gold in Delta.
Bronze is the first level, so read from Bronze it and create next layer. Don't overwrite it. Leave Bronze as is.

If you are using Delta, use the MERGE statement then it takes care of Insert vs Update in one so you dont have to worry about  Append vs Overwrite

I have tried the below approach:
To the Bronze Layer:
bronze_delta_path ="abfss://folder02@lamborginistg.dfs.core.windows.net/bronze/delta-table"
df_transformed.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save(bronze_delta_path)

To the Silver Layer:
silver_delta_path = "abfss://folder02@lamborginistg.dfs.core.windows.net/silver/delta-table"
df_transformed.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save(silver_delta_path)

In the above I wrote to ADLS as Delta table
Because delta give you ability ACID transaction gives , schema enforcement, and time travel capabilities.
I agree with @Ganesh Chandrasekaran
If you have frequent updates, deletions, or complex transformations, Delta Lake is the best. Because using the MERGE statement it takes care of Insert & Update so it handle Append & Overwrite For saving data into the Silver layer
Reference: Delta Lake vs. Parquet Comparison

Delta should be the go to format, since in the backend it anyways saves data in parquet, but also gives you an additional transactional layer, which lets you do schema evolution, ACID transactions and time travel.
